# Document set edit form and adding a list with people picker

Tags: document-set, forms-7

I am working with OOB SharePoint 2013 to create a system for our department projects. I have a document library(Projects) I am using the document set content type for each project.

I have list(Resources) with a lookup (Project ID) that looks up the ID in the Projects folder. It also includes a person/group picker.

Here's the issue:
Going to to the Document Set edit form I created (ProjectEdit)

> https://sites.sp.com/teams/Projects/Forms/ProjectEdit.aspx?List=de31a785-83a7-4e47-b668-457f2492fbea&ID=2&Source=/teams/Projects/Forms/Document%20Set/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=2&FolderCTID=0x0120D52000AEB3B4191991C245B93EFBE0A9F14364&List=de31a785-83a7-4e47-b668-457f2492fbea&RootFolder=%2Fteams%2Fls%2FProjects%2FAnother%20test&RecSrc=%2Fteams%2FProjects%2FAnother%20test&RootFolder=ProjectTracker/Anothertest&Web=4cbaeac1-4cac-477b-928f-6c52fc95dbee#InplviewHash14779b65-c72d-44cf-8e27-5a45757c07b0=FilterField1=Project%5Fx0020%5FID-FilterValue1=2-ShowInGrid=True

I can edit the page to add the Resources list and save the page.

ISSUE: For some reason every time I try to add a person, or pick a person, the list throws and error on the name. 
*"Invalid file name.
The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to access the file."*

[image]

FYI I have confirmed the name is entered correctly.

However if I go to

> https://sites.sp.com/teams/Projects/Forms/ProjectEdit.aspx?List=de31a785-83a7-4e47-b668-457f2492fbea&ID=2&Source=https://sites.sp.com/teams/Projects/Forms/AllItems.aspx&Web=4cbaeac1-4cac-477b-928f-6c52fc95dbee#InplviewHash14779b65-c72d-44cf-8e27-5a45757c07b0=FilterField1=Project%5Fx0020%5FID-FilterValue1=2-ShowInGrid=True

I can edit the page and add the Resources list with no error BUT then I'm not able to get the Document sets documents to display using the document Set Contents web part.

I need to be able to edit a document set and have the Resources and Document Set contents display and allow for edits/updates in place in the form.

Comment: I think this is a similar issue with regards to using Forms7 in the new/edit/view forms: https://forms7.codeplex.com/discussions/538751 and is still unresolved.  I think the developer is on vacation.